# Bash script substring on $(pwd)? Bad substitution error

Tags: bash, substring

I'm trying to do a substring on bash and I'm following this Bash scripting [cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/bash).

```
echo $(pwd)

> Successfully outputs the current working DIR
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to slice the `$(pwd)` at the index 2. I know it's possible to omit the length, to return the rest of the string from that position.

So I'm doing this, and I'm getting the `bad substitution` error.

```
echo ${$(pwd):2}

> bash: ${$(pwd):2}: bad substitution
```

Comment: ${ } seems to be expecting a variable and not a value. $(pwd) seems to be a string. Maybe you'll need an intermediate variable or another way to check for pwd: DIR=$(pwd) && ${DIR:2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused between command substitution with parameter substitution.

In your particular situation you will need to read the command substitution of pwd into a variable first and then use that for parameter expansion and so:

```
pworkd=$(pwd)
echo ${$(pworkd):2}
```

Comment: Of course, Bash already has `$PWD` which is a "magical" built-in; so you can say `echo "${PWD:2}"` directly. (Notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable))